# Detect hotmail login to grant access automatically to JAVA web app

Tags: java, session, web-applications, detect, hotmail

There's the situation. I have a JAVA web app (CDI with Seam 3 modules) with a login. If the guest hasn't login in the application, when he/she enters the application, it must appear the login window, but if the user has a hotmail session active, i want that the java application detect that login and let the user access automatically to the application without login.

When a user goes to the index page of the web app i want to detect if there's a hotmail session active, if exists, i want to recover the email only and look it in the users table and if it matches, redirect the user to the homepage, otherwise, if there's no hotmail session active or the email isn't registered in the users table, just load the login.

I don't know if exists a JAVA library to achieve that or something like that, because i looked for it in the stack overflow questions but only talks about check the email or login to hotmail from java app but i don't want that, i want to check an active session in hotmail and get the email of the session.

Regards.